# Oracle: Split text field on newline

Tags: oracle, line-breaks

I need to merge a couple of tables, once of which has a single Address field, the 2nd which as 3 address line fields.

The single address field in the 1st table includes line breaks.

How can I split this field into 3?

Update:

Turns out some records had CHR(10) || CHR(13), others CHR(13) || CHR(10), and yet others just CHAR(13).  Regardless, the accepted solution below works. A useful way to tell is

```
select dump(field) from table;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your linebreak character is CHR(10), something like the following should work:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(addr, '(.*)' || CHR(10) || '.*' || CHR(10) || '.*', '\1')) AS STREET_ADDR,
       TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(addr, '.*' || CHR(10) || '(.*)' || CHR(10) || '.*', '\1')) AS CITY,
       TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(addr, '.*' || CHR(10) || '.*' || CHR(10) || '(.*)', '\1')) AS STATE
      FROM addr_table;
```

If addr_table is populated using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO addr_table(addr)
VALUES('12345 MY STREET' || CHR(10) || 'NOWHERESVILLE' || CHR(10) || 'ASTATE');
```

the above SELECT will return

```
STREET_ADDR     CITY            STATE
12345 MY STREET NOWHERESVILLE   ASTATE
```

Share and enjoy